# Get the internal name from documents with REST sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest

I'm trying to get the **Name** from some documents using REST, i'm doing it with the following endpoint:

> `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=*&$filter=ContentType eq 'Document'`

It gives me a lot of properties except **Name**, how can i achieve this?

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=*,File/Name&$expand=File
```